# WordPress: Allow image hotlinking in one folder, or one specific image in folder inside theme?

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess, hotlinking

How to allow images to be hotlinked from one folder, or just one image.
I have tried this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^wp-content/themes/mytheme/image-folder/images/pictures/.+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^wp-content/themes/mytheme/image-folder/images/img/photo.png $
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

But this does not work.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: _But this does not work_? What not work?

Comment: Allowed folder and image file are prohibited. Can't be hotlinked.